# D3: Select SVG attribute and change it

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

if I have an SVG...

```
var canvasBars = d3.select("#chart1").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)    
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate("+margin.left+","+margin.top+")");
```

If I modify the width variable (used to calculate the width attribute)  How do I then select the width attribute and modify it with this new width variable?

this does not seem to work:

```
canvasBars.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your other option is to ensure the former 'canvasBars' variable is actually the canvas.

```
var svgSelection = d3.select("#chart1").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)

var baseGroup = svgSelection.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate("+margin.left+","+margin.top+")");
```

Your former 'canvasBars' I have renamed to 'svgSelection'.  If you want to modify the "canvas" directly, your former idea will now work.

```
svgSelection.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right);
```